# setting textview content to bottom in relativelayout

Tags: android, xml

I have textview in relativelayout and my goal is to set text to bottom (and center) of this textview. I used android:gravity="center|bottom" in textview XML, but it didn't work when I run the app. Here is my code:

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your textview:

```
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't help, this method set textview at the bottom of relativelayout, but what I wanted is to set text at the bottom of textview.

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer, I think having set text in code programmatically, gravity was changing, so to set text I used SpannableString and it worked.